# Android Parse JSON String for Listview within View Flipper

Tags: android, listview

I'm just trying to parse a simple JSON string in the following format: ["X","Y","Z"] and put it into a listview. The listview is within a view flipper in order to have tabs visible at all times throughout the app.

The problem i'm having is the app is stopping unexpectedly, here is the full code for the main launching activity:

```
public class Activity extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button doSomething;
TabHost tabHost;
ViewFlipper flipper;
ListView listview;
HttpResponse re;
String json;
JSONObject j;



@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.tablayout_1);




    doSomething = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_do_something);
    doSomething.setOnClickListener(this);

    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.layout_tab_one);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);







   //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,this.fetch());



   listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    flipper.setOnClickListener(this);

    String tabname1 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab1);
    String tabname2 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab2);
    String tabname3 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab3);
    String tabname4 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab4);

    tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_one).setIndicator(tabname1));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_two).setIndicator(tabname2));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_three).setIndicator(tabname3));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_four).setIndicator(tabname4));

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);




    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
             flipper.showNext();


        }});




}



public ArrayList<String> fetch()
{
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        URL twitter = new URL(
                "JSON.php");
        URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));


        String line; 


        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {




      //make sure youe String line is completely filled after that..
      if (!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("") && line.startsWith("[")) 
       {
      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(line);
      for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 
       {
          JSONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         // also make sure you get the value from the jsonObject using some key
         // like, jobj.getString("country");

         listItems.add(jobj.getString("")); 
       }
          }

        } 

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listItems;
}





@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

Log output:

```
    08-25 19:29:48.544: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(850): Shutting down VM
08-25 19:29:48.544: WARN/dalvikvm(850): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.android/com.app.android.Activity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1038)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:523)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at com.android.Activity.fetch(Activity.java:193)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at com.android.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:144)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
    08-25 19:29:48.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     ... 11 more
```

Ok the app is launching now but the listview is not being populated with the JSON Strings for some reason?

Comment: If you have a problem with the app crashing, then post the stack trace.

Comment: The logcat output would help us A LOT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is throwing a [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), and the documentation says this about it:

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

Looking at your code, you call `fetch()` in your `onCreate()`, which runs on the UI Thread.  You will need to do this in a background thread (or target an SDK version less than Honeycomb).  Take a look at [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for some more info on this solution.

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,this.fetch());
```

Comment: Ok thats launching now, but the listview is not being populated for some reason

Comment: You will have to either update your question, or ask a new one.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question.  Provide your NEW code, giving the detail you did in this question.

Comment: Ok i'll do that, new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197300/android-listview-not-being-populated-with-json-strings