# Android Listview not being populated with JSON Strings

Tags: android, listview

I have an app that has a viewflipper to keep tabs in view at all times throughout the app, and a listview below the tabs. I'm trying to populate the list view with JSON strings from a web server, the web server is feeding JSON strings in the following format: ["X","Y","Z"]
So basically, I want to have the list view in list each string on a different row.

The app is launching ok, the list view just appears to be empty. 
This is the tutorial I used: http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/simple-android-json-parsing-example-with-output-into-listactivity/
Here is the full code the main launching activity:

```
public class Activity extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button doSomething;
    TabHost tabHost;
    ViewFlipper flipper;
    ListView listview;
    HttpResponse re;
    String json;
    JSONObject j;




    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.tablayout_1);




        doSomething = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_do_something);
        doSomething.setOnClickListener(this);

        flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.layout_tab_one);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);







       //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,this.fetch());



       listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        flipper.setOnClickListener(this);

        String tabname1 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab1);
        String tabname2 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab2);
        String tabname3 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab3);
        String tabname4 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab4);

        tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_one).setIndicator(tabname1));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_two).setIndicator(tabname2));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_three).setIndicator(tabname3));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_four).setIndicator(tabname4));

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);




        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                 flipper.showNext();


            }});




    }



    public ArrayList<String> fetch()
    {
        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            URL twitter = new URL(
                    "JSON.php");
            URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tc.getInputStream()));


            String line;


            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {




          //make sure youe String line is completely filled after that..
          if (!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("") && line.startsWith("[")) 
           {
          JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(line);
          for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 
           {
              JSONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             // also make sure you get the value from the jsonObject using some key
             // like, jobj.getString("country");

             listItems.add(jobj.toString()); 
           }
              }

            } 

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listItems;
    }





    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Error in Log Cat:

```
 08-25 21:38:15.742: ERROR/InputDispatcher(81): channel '40a14e38 com.app.android/com.app.android.Activity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
```

Update, here are the values of jArray as reported by Logcat:

08-26 16:49:07.246: VERBOSE/app(472): jarray value: ["Country1","Country2","Country3"]

These are the correct values!

Ok stepping into the loop, log out outputs the following:

```
08-26 16:59:55.756: WARN/System.err(506): org.json.JSONException: Value Country1 at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-26 16:59:55.756: WARN/System.err(506):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
08-26 16:59:55.766: WARN/System.err(506):     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:484)
08-26 16:59:55.775: WARN/System.err(506):     at com.app.android.Activity.fetch(Activity.java:165)
08-26 16:59:55.775: WARN/System.err(506):     at com.app.android.Activity.onCreate(eActivity.java:93)
08-26 16:59:55.786: WARN/System.err(506):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
08-26 16:59:55.786: WARN/System.err(506):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
08-26 16:59:55.795: WARN/System.err(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
08-26 16:59:55.806: WARN/System.err(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
08-26 16:59:55.806: WARN/System.err(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-26 16:59:55.815: WARN/System.err(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
08-26 16:59:55.815: WARN/System.err(506):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 16:59:55.826: WARN/System.err(506):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-26 16:59:55.826: WARN/System.err(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
08-26 16:59:55.836: WARN/System.err(506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 16:59:55.836: WARN/System.err(506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-26 16:59:55.846: WARN/System.err(506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-26 16:59:55.855: WARN/System.err(506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-26 16:59:55.855: WARN/System.err(506):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem could be that your URL is just "JSON.php". You dont specify the server this resides on (http://somewebsite.com/JSON.php). What happens when you set debug points and step through? Whats the value of the twitter URL after its created? My guess is that it cannot reach this "JSON.php".

EDIT: Try this:

Instead of using

```
JSONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

Try

```
String country = jArray.getString(i);
listItems.add(country);
```

Comment: JSON.php is just an example of URL, i'm actually using a local php server for the JSON feed but i've tested the url in my web browser and it works fine, would it be something to do with the layout?

Comment: Set a debug point right in the middle of your loop that reads the json to see what the values are. Do you have any data coming back?

Comment: Yea I was just wondering how would I go about checking if the data is coming back, is there a way to print out values?

Comment: If you use eclipse, to the left of your code, there is a vertical bar where you can double click to set break points (to the left of the line numbers). Set a break point, and then instead of "Running" your app, "Debug" your app. Your code will stop where you specify, then you use F6 to step through each piece. Hover over any created variable to see its value at that time.

Comment: Ok I stepped into the loop but I don't see any values, all I see is functions, pressing F6 increases the line number

Comment: Please see http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html for help on debugging. Yes you actually step through your created functions, line by line. After a line executes, if a variable was created/changed/disposed of you can HOVER over it with your mouse to see its exact value.

Comment: Ok I put a Log.d statement in the fetch function to see how far it gets, it doesn't show after the following line:  JSONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: What is the value of jArray when debugging? If you can't debug then you are going to have serious problems in your life as a developer :)

Comment: Please see above for the values I got for jArray from log cat

Comment: Alrighty, now what happens when you debug and step through your loop that adds the items to the list?

Comment: Please see above for logcat outputs from loop

Comment: Ok that worked! :) The only thing is, everything seems to be on the list twice

Comment: Sorry I had the listItems.add statement there twice, thanks for your help.

Comment: Great! Please remember to mark as answered using the big check mark.